# Virtuoso appears to be installed... but isn't (and won't run)

Tags: virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I've followed [the instructions](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/stable/7) to install the [stable branch of Virtuoso Open Source 7](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/tree/stable/7) on Ubuntu 16.04. There don't appear to be any errors throughout the process of —

```
./autogen.sh  
CFLAGS="-O2 -m64" 
export CFLAGS 
./configure 
make 
make install
```

However, when I go to `/usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db` (which contains only `virtuoso.ini`) and run —

```
virtuoso-t -f &
```

The first time I do this the terminal just vanishes. When I reopen the terminal and run the same again it just reads `The program 'virtuoso-t' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt install virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin`.

I've tried installing both 7 stable and develop from github and both produce the same result. I'd rather use 7 but tried installing 6 via the ubuntu package and conductor wouldn't work for me - not having much luck all round, one of those days.

Thanks for assistance you can provide.

Comment: Did you adjust your `$PATH` variable after `make install`? `$PATH` should include the path to the directory which contains the `virtuoso-t`, *or* you can include that path in the launch command, e.g., `/path/to/virtuoso-t -f -c /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini &`. (`develop/7` is recommended over `stable/7` at the moment, due to the number of fixes there.)

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. Thanks @TallTed, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't adjust your `$PATH` variable after `make install`.

`$PATH` should include the path to the directory which contains the `virtuoso-t`, or you can include that path in the launch command, e.g. —

```
/path/to/virtuoso-t -f -c /usr/local/virtuoso-opensource/var/lib/virtuoso/db/virtuoso.ini &
```

(Note that the `develop/7` branch is recommended over `stable/7` at the moment, due to the number of fixes there.)